# Vertical alignment in \table

Tags: tables

In the table below, the spacing is odd and the last two columns overlap. Can you tell me why?

This is the reduced code:

```
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Determinants of PMBs\label{Table 3b}}
\begin{tabular}{l
       S[table-format=1.3]
       S[input-symbols=(), table-format=1.3]
       S[table-format=1.3] 
       S[input-symbols=(), table-format=1.3]}
\toprule
                   & {(1)} & & {(2)} \\

\midrule
SMD tier  &       0.144\sym{**} & (0.062) &  0.144   & (0.150)   \\
PR tier   &      -0.006         & (0.109) & -0.006   & (0.120)   \\

Constant  &      -0.575         & (0.517) & -0.575    & (0.521)   \\

\midrule
alpha     &       0.319\sym{***}& (0.044) & 0.319\sym{***} & (0.087) \\
N         &        {3161}       &         &        {3161}  &          \\

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Model 1 uses robust se, model 2 clustered at the party group level}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Code of the document

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Simoncini Garamond Std}
\usepackage{microtype}
\microtypesetup{final}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}

% pagine e figure
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.8}%

% horizontal tables
\usepackage{rotating}

% tables 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

% tables with numbers
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}}

\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}


\mainmatter
\input{Chapters/1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you post a compilable code, starting from `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That keeps us from guessing how to complete it.

Comment: The line for your first row is missing a `&`, so the column can't get assigned a width.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table-format=1.3` does only reserve space for the numbers. Since your also have negative numbers in some of the columns, you will need `-1.3` instead. Also, there is no space for the asterisks. You can change that by adding `table-space-text-post = {\sym{***}}` in the corresponding columns. Lastly, your `\multicolumn` only spans three of the five columns and the text in it is, if printed in a single line, wider than the whole table. If you replace this by something like `\multicolumn{5}{p{8.5cm}}` the large space between column 3 and 4 will disappear as it allows the text to span all five columns and introduces an autmatic linebreak if the length of the text exceeds 8.5 cm (the approximate width of the table):

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Determinants of PMBs\label{Table 3b}}
\begin{tabular}{l
       S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post = {\sym{***}}]
       S[input-symbols=(), table-format=1.3]
       S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post = {\sym{***}}] 
       S[input-symbols=(), table-format=1.3]}
\toprule
                   & {(1)} & & {(2)} \\

\midrule
SMD tier  &       0.144\sym{**} & (0.062) &  0.144   & (0.150)   \\
PR tier   &      -0.006         & (0.109) & -0.006   & (0.120)   \\

Constant  &      -0.575         & (0.517) & -0.575    & (0.521)   \\

\midrule
alpha     &       0.319\sym{***}& (0.044) & 0.319\sym{***} & (0.087) \\
N         &        {3161}       &         &        {3161}  &          \\

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{p{8.5cm}}{\footnotesize Model 1 uses robust se, model 2 clustered at the party group level}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot